# Unable to install the Bcrypt.Net-Next assembly in to the GAC on Windows 10 using Powershell

Tags: windows, git, powershell, ssis, gac

I need to implement BCrypt hashing in an SSIS package's data flow. I would like to do this by deploying the Bcrypt assembly to the GAC and then calling it in a script component. I downloaded the project from Git, built the strong named project (I created a key), and deployed the assembly to the GAC using Powershell. I used Powershell instead of gacutil.exe because I am running Windows 10, which does not have gacutil.exe.

https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net

```
# NOTE: Run powershell as administrator
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.EnterpriseServices") | Out-Null         
[System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish] $publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish

# to install a dll
$publish.GacInstall("C:\temp\Bcrypt.net\BCrypt.Net-Next.dll")
```

I do not get any error, in fact I do not get any output - it just goes to the next line. But the assembly is not installed in **%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly**

Any idea why this is not working?

Note: I am doing it this way as opposed to using NuGet because I am going to be using this in an SSIS script component. Apparently, NuGet does not work with SSIS solutions.

Comment: I'm dumb to this process so bear with me.  Are you sure it should appear it the assembly directory?  After the command succeeds (presumably), does ISE see the namespace?  [System.Bcrypt.whatever]?

Comment: Yes, it should show up in the Assembly directory. It is a file and needs to be stored somewhere. Can you try building it and deploying it to the GAC?

Comment: At work and no way I can DL random libraries to implement them here.  I'll try when I get home.

Comment: It's open source. The DLL is not in there. You have to build it. Note: I used the strong sign

Comment: So downloading code from GitHub and building it into a DLL is the same problem at work as sideloading a DLL from the Internet--at least as far as work is concerned.  Sorry dude.

Comment: Understood. I'm just letting you know what I went through. If you can look at this tonight that would be great.

Comment: @thepip3r You can check to see what folder name is given to an assembly by running `([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("C:\temp\Bcrypt.net\BCrypt.Net-Next.StrongName.dll")).FullName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complement [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60603484/45375):

I'm surprised that `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.EnterpriseServices')` didn't work - it does for me, but it's a moot point, because **in PowerShell it's preferable to use

[`Add-Type -AssemblyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type)**, which:

- is more PowerShell-idiomatic in terms of its syntax, and
- reports a (statement-terminating) *error* if the assembly cannot be loaded (whereas `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName()` is a *quiet no-op* in case of failure to load the assembly).

```
# Try to load the latest System.EnterpriseServices.dll assembly
# from the GAC.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.EnterpriseServices
```

Like [`[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName), `Add-Type -AssemblyName` allows you to load GAC assemblies by their *simple name* (as also reflected in the DLL/executable file name without extension), which neither requires you to know the assembly's *version number* nor its *public key* (however, `Add-Type -AssemblyName` does *not* also first look in the *application* directory, which in PowerShell would presumably be the location of the PowerShell executable itself).

Note that **`[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName()` is officially declared *obsolete***, because **loading assemblies by *simple name* can break existing code later**, due to installation of incompatible versions or assemblies with duplicate simple names.

However, **in a *late-bound scripting language* such as PowerShell, loading by simple name may be acceptable (`Add-Type -AssemblyName` is *not* obsolete)**, and simplifies loading (you *can* specify an assembly's unambiguous *full name*, however - see below).

<sup>Of course, if `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.EnterpriseServices')` inexplicably didn't work for you, `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.EnterpriseServices` may similarly fail, but the general point stands.</sup>

The recommended replacement for `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName()` is **[`[Reflection.Assembly]::Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.Load)**, which is what you ended up using. It **requires you to know the assembly's *full name***, which must include the assembly's ***full version number* and its *public key*** - although a *lower* version number than the one actually present in the GAC is seemingly accepted.

Note that **`Add-Type -AssemblyName` accepts (strong-named) full assembly names** too:

```
# Load from the GAC by *full assembly name*.
# Equivalent of [Reflection.Assembly]::Load()
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

---

Taking a step back:

**I suggest avoiding putting a custom assembly in the GAC:**, for two reasons:

- PowerShell [Core] 6+, which will eventually make Windows PowerShell obsolete, is built on .NET *Core*, which *doesn't have a GAC anymore*, so you'll need a different approach when you migrate.

  - In PowerShell [Core], `Add-Type -AssemblyName` looks for assemblies given by simple name among the assemblies that ship with PowerShell itself, though it looks in the *current* directory first.
- The  [`System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.enterpriseservices.internal.publish) type you're using isn't officially supported for direct use: "`Publish` is used internally by the .NET Framework. You do not need to use it directly in your code.", and the only officially supported way to install assemblies in the GAC is via *Windows Installer* (`gacutil.exe` is only meant to be used during *development*).

---

Instead, I **recommend the following approach**:

- **Author an *auxiliary PowerShell module* that wraps the assembly of interest**, named, say, `BCrypt`.
- **Place that module in one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`**, so that any script executing `Import-Module BCrypt` implicitly loads the assembly of interest into the session.

Such a module is easy to author:

- Choose a suitable directory listed in `$env:PSModulePath` and create a subdirectory named, say, `BCrypt` in it.
- Copy your assembly DLL (`BCrypt.Net-Next.dll`) into that subdirectory.
- Change to the subdirectory and create a module manifest `BCrypt.psd1` there:

  ```
    New-ModuleManifest BCrypt.psd1 -RequiredAssemblies BCrypt.Net-Next.dll -ModuleVersion 1.0
  ```

Provide additional [`New-ModuleManifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) arguments as needed and/or edit the module manifest after the fact, as needed.

Comment: How would I create an Windows Installer for an assembly only (not an application)? At this point, I need for the assembly to be available at the global level so any project/solution can reference it. So, in a project, when I right click on references, I will be able to add whatever assembly I just built.

Comment: Link to the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65982471/45375

Answer (score 4):

The Powershell script I was using is incorrect.

Instead of using `LoadWithPartialName`, we must use `Load`

```
# NOTE: Run powershell as administrator
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publisher = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish

# to uninstall a dll
$publisher.GacRemove("C:\temp\Bcrypt.net\BCrypt.Net-Next.StrongName.dll")

# to install a dll
$publisher.GacInstall("C:\temp\Bcrypt.net\BCrypt.Net-Next.StrongName.dll")
```

This will install the assembly into the following path:

**%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\BCrypt.Net-Next.StrongName\v4.0_3.2.1.0__cb41ca561ed0708f\BCrypt.Net-Next.StrongName.dll**

Note: I am using the most recent version available on Git, which is 3.2.1. So, future releases will result in a different sub-folder path as seen above (i.e., v4.0_*).

The challenge here is that I still do not see the assembly available in any of the script component's references. I will continue to research this and post a new question if needed.